# parsing language params in widget=BootstrapDateInput()?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

How to pass language params to [BootstrapDateInput](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap-toolkit)

What about?

```
widget=BootstrapDateInput(language="pt-BR")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The widget uses `translation.get_language()` to get the current language.

If you want to force a locale, you can set it manually, e.g.:

```
from django.utils import translation
translation.activate('pt-BR')
widget=BootstrapDateInput()
```

If you only use one language, set it in your settings.py:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'
```

In django-bootstrap-toolkit's versions before 2.11.5 there was an issue with the widget, which caused the widget to always use the same language-specific JS file, instead of using the one appropriate for the current language. This means that most likely, only the language set in `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE` would be supported by the widget, and it would default to English otherwise.

The issue has been fixed in version 2.11.5.